# How to read a pdf in landscape orientation in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, landscape-portrait, pypdf

I have a pdf file that´s in portrait orientation, but in some pages, the **text** is in landscape orientation. When using PyPDF2 to read the page above I get this text from extractText() function:

```
page.extractText()
```

Out[24]: "U ~ 00  w . T•~,  ca o rn o\ rn rn rn ~ >, p y ro • ti† ~ a ~ v CN d V1 U á x ~ U bb Q P ~ O U y ~ ~ á ~ ~ ~ F~ o vl VI † I~ p * 00 p † N ó † O cn 0 † v l o ~ O 7 0  † '_ ' `aIs s~`Ł ~ Y ~ ~ O ~ pp p . p vl p O' O O O F-1 F cn W >1 ~ kn ~ --i N •--i r ~ F•N r.' ~ CD †r p o p o 0 G v VI W ~ Ł U ~ W o ^ o 3 .-. .-. o O .-. O O in M ~on vl 3 ó ó ò ó ò ~ a ~ tn . mó00 woNN  p 00 a+ -fl  n~n a O ;~ o ~^ o a. ~ … — — — — — •• •• • N ~ G_ L' U U U 0 3ed~ — a o o ~ •†zce  bp eV+ wb0 CI ce a tn ~O ~ I "

Here is an example of pages I'm trying to extract the text:
[Portrait page, landscape text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvbsx.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't read the text, if OCR did not put the text into the PDF document.

Try using pdflatex or a word processor to produce similar mixed orientation documents, and extractText from them for comparison.

Consider helping out your OCR package by skewing the image through an angle of close to 90 degrees, prior to the text recognition phase.

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering wether there was another way to solve the problem without another OCR procedure.